# ArguementError First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `ArgumentError: First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty` when I add the line `render 'users/index', layout: 'new_application'` to the index action.

The error points to the view on line `= form_for @search do |f|`

I have two search options on the page, one a basic search using thinking sphinx and another is a advanced search from scratch. The advanced search works fine, it's just the index action for thinking sphinx that throws the error.

Searches controller:

```
  def new
    @search = Search.new
    render layout: 'new_application'

  def index
        @users = User.search(params[:search])            
        end      
        render 'users/index', layout: 'new_application'    
      end 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@search` is not instantiated in your index action

```
def index
  ..
  @search = Search.new
  ..
end
```